# How to use number pad Keys in Qt?

Tags: qt, events, key, numpad

The Qt::Key enum has no number pad specific numeric definitions. So how would one go about distinguishing between a number pressed on the number pad vs a number on the number row? I know the events at the OS level are different.
Enter and Return on the other hand are separate keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keyPressEvent->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::KeypadModifier)`.

Comment: This was the correct path. I actually used a QKeyCombination(Qt::Key_7|Qt::KeypadModifier) for a QShortcut connected to a lambda slot